# Get the top Facebook fan pages - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any documentation in Facebook API, which gives the top facebook fan pages in Android SDK, or else suggestions for the facebook pages

For example: for TaylorSwift page, should get suggestions like Adele, Rihanna etc.,

Answer (score 1):

There's no API for suggesting Pages in the Gaph API. Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference

Comment: thanks for the info. is there any way to get the TOP FAN FACEBOOK PAGES....where as this website http://fanpagelist.com/category/top_users/ gives..

Comment: No. They are pulling daily stats and compute the list themselve. Read the docs!